PySide6: No QtMultimedia backends found
After upgrading to Windows 11, the audio is not playing and this warning appears:
No QtMultimedia backends found. Only QMediaDevices, QAudioDevice, QSoundEffect, QAudioSink, and QAudioSource are available.
Failed to initialize QMediaPlayer "Not available"

Minimal code example:
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.media = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.output = QAudioOutput(parent=self)
        self.media.setAudioOutput(self.output)
        self.media.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("files/media/theme.mp3"))

    def showEvent(self, e) -> None:
        self.media.play()
        super().showEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

Only found information that the default should be DirectShow, which in turn is part of DirectX, which is already installed.

Python 3.11
Windows 11 Pro 23H2 22631.3296
PySide6 6.6.3

UPD: After rolling back PySide6 to version 6.6.0 everything worked.
However, ideally it would work on the newest version as well.

Actually, the default backend should be ffmpeg on almost all platforms (including Windows) since Qt 6.5. It may be an issue with the specific PySide version, though. How did you install it? You mentioned a downgrade, have you tried to completely uninstall and reinstall it again?

@musicamante
pip install PySide6
Yes, I have tried a complete uninstall and reinstall. I've created new virtual environments, changed disks where the project and virtual environment are located (you never know, I thought I'd try anything I could think of).

Apparently there's a new release (6.6.3.1) that should fix some problems with the multimedia plugins on Windows.

Same issue on PyQt6.7 with Windows 11 Pro 10.0.22631 Build 22631
